# Instantly abort Lua Script

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

When i press mouse 1 script will press and hold "x" key for 5000 ms, wait 200 ms and repeat the cycle until i release the mouse 1 .

Issue is even if i release the key early the script will run for 5000 ms, looking for way to exit the script immediately if i release the mouse 1.

Thanks

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
function OnEvent(event, arg)
if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
                if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then


    repeat
            PressKey("x")
Sleep(5000)
ReleaseKey("x")
Sleep(200)



                    until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)


        end                     
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Split 5 sec into small 200ms intervals

```
EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if IsKeyLockOn("numlock" )then
    if IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then
      repeat
        PressKey("x")
        for i = 1, 5000/200 do
          Sleep(200)
          if not IsMouseButtonPressed(1) then break end
        end
        ReleaseKey("x")
        Sleep(200)
      until not IsMouseButtonPressed(1)
    end                     
  end
end
```